# Determining winner and winning hand in poker (holdem)

Tags: java, beginner, game, playing-cards, stream

I wrote couple classes that calculate winner, winning hand and winning hands rank (straight, flush, fullhouse etc.). I searched for something similar, but only found posts where five cards are used, but in a holdem there are cards  7 cards and have to choose best 5 of them.

**How it works:**

You pass `List<Card> cards` to `HandRanker::getRank` method and retrieve an object `PokerHand` that contains a hand rank(flush, straight etc) and cards that contains that hand.

In `HandRanker` class it goes into each ranks method and updates `handCards` and `handValue` fields and if they do so method returns true and `handValue` object is returned.

---

I think it's all working fine. When I was writing code I did a little testing, but haven't written any unit tests yet.

**HandRanker.java**

```
    package poker;

import static deck.Card.*;
import static poker.PokerHand.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

import deck.Card;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class HandRanker {
    public static final int FULL_HAND = 5;
    public static final int FLUSH = FULL_HAND;
    public static final int STRAIGHT = FULL_HAND;
    public static final int FULL_HOUSE = FULL_HAND;
    public static final int QUADS = 4;
    public static final int SET = 3;
    public static final int PAIR = 2;
    public static final int HIGH_CARD = 1;

    public static final List<EnumSet<RANK>> STRAIGHTS = setPossibleStraights();
    private static final HandRanker instance = new HandRanker();

    public static HandRanker getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private List<Card> handCards = new ArrayList<>();
    private PokerHand pokerHand;

    private HandRanker() {}

    private static List<EnumSet<RANK>> setPossibleStraights() {
        List<EnumSet<RANK>> straights =  EnumSet.range(RANK.TWO, RANK.TEN).stream()
            .map(rank -> EnumSet.range(rank, RANK.values()[rank.ordinal() + STRAIGHT - 1]))
            .collect(toList());
        Collections.reverse(straights);
        straights.add(EnumSet.of(RANK.ACE, RANK.TWO, RANK.THREE, RANK.FOUR, RANK.FIVE));
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(straights);
    }

    public PokerHand getRank(List<Card> allCards) {
        if(allCards.size() != 7) throw new IllegalArgumentException("You have to pass 7 cards");

        if(isStraightFlush(allCards) ||
               isFourOfAKind(allCards) ||
               isFullHouse(allCards) ||
               isFlush(allCards, true) ||
               isStraight(allCards) ||
               isSet(allCards) ||
               isTwoPair(allCards) ||
               isPair(allCards) ||
               isHighCard(allCards)) {}
        return pokerHand;
    }


    private boolean isStraightFlush(List<Card> allCards) {
        if(isFlush(allCards, false) && isStraight(handCards)) {
            pokerHand = new PokerHand(HAND_RANK.STRAIGHT_FLUSH, handCards);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isFlush(List<Card> allCards, boolean finalResult) {
        Map<SUIT, Long> suitsMap = getSuitMap(allCards);
        SUIT popularSuit = getMostPopularSuit(suitsMap);

        if(suitsMap.get(popularSuit) >= FLUSH) {

            if(finalResult) {
                handCards = allCards.stream()
                    .filter(c -> c.getSuit() == popularSuit)
                    .sorted()
                    .limit(FULL_HAND)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

                pokerHand = new PokerHand(HAND_RANK.FLUSH, handCards);
            } else {
                handCards = allCards.stream()
                    .filter(c -> c.getSuit() == popularSuit)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isStraight(List<Card> allCards) {
        EnumSet<RANK> ranks = allCards.stream()
            .map(Card::getRank)
            .collect(toCollection(() -> EnumSet.noneOf(RANK.class)));

        for(Set<RANK> straight : STRAIGHTS) {
            if(ranks.containsAll(straight))  {
                handCards = allCards.stream()
                    .filter(c -> straight.contains(c.getRank()))
                    .collect(toList());

                pokerHand = new PokerHand(HAND_RANK.STRAIGHT, handCards);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isFourOfAKind(List<Card> allCards) {
        handCards = getHighestCards(allCards, QUADS);

        if(handCards.size() == QUADS) {
            handCards.addAll(getMultipleHighestCards(allCards, FULL_HAND - QUADS));
            pokerHand = new PokerHand(HAND_RANK.FOUR_OF_A_KIND, handCards);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isFullHouse(List<Card> allCards) {
        handCards = getHighestCards(allCards, SET);
        handCards.addAll(getHighestCards(allCards, PAIR));

        if(handCards.size() == FULL_HOUSE) {
            pokerHand = new PokerHand(HAND_RANK.FULL_HOUSE, handCards);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isSet(List<Card> allCards) {
        handCards = getHighestCards(allCards, SET);

        if(handCards.size() == SET) {
            handCards.addAll(getMultipleHighestCards(allCards, FULL_HAND - SET));
            pokerHand = new PokerHand(HAND_RANK.THREE_OF_A_KIND, handCards);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isTwoPair(List<Card> allCards) {
        handCards= getHighestCards(allCards, PAIR);
        allCards.removeAll(handCards);
        handCards.addAll(getHighestCards(allCards, PAIR));

        if(handCards.size() == PAIR + PAIR) {
            handCards.addAll(getMultipleHighestCards(allCards, FULL_HAND - PAIR - PAIR));
            pokerHand = new PokerHand(HAND_RANK.TWO_PAIR, handCards);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isPair(List<Card> allCards) {
        handCards = getHighestCards(allCards, PAIR);

        if(handCards.size() == PAIR) {
            handCards.addAll(getMultipleHighestCards(allCards, FULL_HAND - PAIR));
            pokerHand = new PokerHand(HAND_RANK.PAIR, handCards);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isHighCard(List<Card> allCards) {
        handCards = getHighestCards(allCards, FULL_HAND);
        pokerHand = new PokerHand(HAND_RANK.HIGH_CARD, handCards);
        return true;
    }

    private List<Card> getHighestCards(List<Card> allCards, int count) {
        EnumMap<RANK, Long> ranks = getRankMap(allCards);

        try {
            RANK cardsRank = ranks.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == count)
                .reduce((previous, current) -> current)
                .get().getKey(); //throws exception if there is not same rank cards with specified count

            return allCards.stream()
                .filter( c -> c.getRank() == cardsRank)
                .collect(toList());
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    private List<Card> getMultipleHighestCards(List<Card> allCards, int count) {
        List<Card> highestCards = new ArrayList<>(count);
        for(int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
            List<Card> cards = getHighestCards(allCards, HIGH_CARD);
            allCards.removeAll(cards);
            highestCards.addAll(cards);
        }
        return highestCards;
    }

    private SUIT getMostPopularSuit(Map<SUIT, Long> suits) {
        return suits.entrySet().stream()
            .max((lhs, rhs) -> lhs.getValue() > rhs.getValue() ? 1 : -1)
            .get().getKey();
    }

    private EnumMap<SUIT, Long> getSuitMap(List<Card> allCards) {
        return allCards.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(
                    Card::getSuit,
                    () -> new EnumMap<>(SUIT.class),
                    counting()
                ));
    }

    private EnumMap<RANK, Long> getRankMap(List<Card> allCards) {
        return allCards.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(
                    Card::getRank,
                    () -> new EnumMap<>(RANK.class),
                    counting()
                ));
    }
}
```

**Card.java**

```
package deck;

public class Card implements Comparable {

    public static enum SUIT {
        SPADES,
        HEARTS,
        CLUBS,
        DIAMONDS
    }

    public static enum RANK {
        TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5),
        SIX(6), SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8), NINE(9),
        TEN(10), JACK(11), QUEEN(12), KING(13), ACE(14);

        private final int value;

        private RANK(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    private final RANK rank;
    private final SUIT suit;

    public Card(RANK rank, SUIT suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public RANK getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public SUIT getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Card{" +
            "rank=" + rank +
            ", suit=" + suit +
            '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if(this == o) return 0;
        if(o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return 0;

        Card card = (Card) o;

        if(rank.getValue() > card.rank.getValue()) return -1;
        if(rank.getValue() < card.rank.getValue()) return 1;
        return 0;
    }

}
```

**Pokerhand.java**

```
package poker;

import deck.Card;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class PokerHand implements Comparable {
    public static enum HAND_RANK {
        HIGH_CARD(0),
        PAIR(1),
        TWO_PAIR(2),
        THREE_OF_A_KIND(3),
        STRAIGHT(4),
        FLUSH(5),
        FULL_HOUSE(6),
        FOUR_OF_A_KIND(7),
        STRAIGHT_FLUSH(8);

        private final int value;

        HAND_RANK(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    private final HAND_RANK handRank;
    private final List<Card> cards;

    public PokerHand(HAND_RANK handRank, List<Card> cards) {
        if(cards.size() != HandRanker.FULL_HAND) throw new IllegalArgumentException("You have to pass five cards");
        this.handRank = handRank;
        this.cards = cards;
        Collections.sort(this.cards); //sorts for compareTo method
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "HandValue{" +
            "handRank=" + handRank +
            ", allCards=" + cards +
            '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if(this == o) return 0;
        if(o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return 0;

        PokerHand pokerHand = (PokerHand) o;

        if(handRank.getValue() > pokerHand.handRank.getValue()) return 1;
        if(handRank.getValue() < pokerHand.handRank.getValue()) return -1;

        for(int index = 0; index < cards.size(); index++) {
            if(cards.get(index).getRank().getValue() > pokerHand.cards.get(index).getRank().getValue()) return 1;
            if(cards.get(index).getRank().getValue() < pokerHand.cards.get(index).getRank().getValue()) return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

### 1. Any suggestions how to do it better?

Should I write some between class for easier testing. Now it would look like this:

```
@Test
public void testStraight() {
List<Card> cards = new ArrayList();
cards.add(new Card(RANK.ACE, SUIT.DIAMONDS));
cards.add(new Card(RANK.ACE, SUIT.SPADES));
cards.add(new Card(RANK.ACE, SUIT.HEARTS));
....
....
assertEquals(HandRanker.getInstance(cards), resultCards);
}
```

You can imagine how much lines it would take to properly test everything.

### 2. How could I make `HandRanker` class structure better?

Now it seems very fragile. I'f I change one thing whole class breaks apart.
This was the best way I could think of implementing:

```
 public PokerHand getRank(List<Card> allCards) {
        if(allCards.size() != 7) throw new IllegalArgumentException("You have to pass 7 cards");

   if(isStraightFlush(allCards) ||
           isFourOfAKind(allCards) ||
           isFullHouse(allCards) ||
           isFlush(allCards, true) ||
           isStraight(allCards) ||
           isSet(allCards) ||
           isTwoPair(allCards) ||
           isPair(allCards) ||
           isHighCard(allCards)) {}
    return pokerHand;
}
```

To me it seems I'm exploiting stuff that I shouldn't do. Is this a good approach? Is there something I haven't thought of?

Also relying on sorting when getting higher card at index 0 in a list seems wrong. If I ever change that `Card` class `HandRanker` class will fail.

### 3. Should I get rid of this sort of responsibilities?

### 4. Other things that are not industry standard?

Comment: It looks like project Euler's problem 54, did you solve it?

Comment: I just googled it. In theory I should be able to solve it with this code.  Will do it now.

Comment: I've just solved it and posted [my code for a review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/87991/14363).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Card

The names `SUIT` and `RANK` should be `Suit` and `Rank`. I'm not sure about your `compareTo` for two reasons:

- It's inconsistent with `equals`, which is allowed, but should be avoided if possible and really should be documented.
- It accepts any object, but should accept `Card` only

```
if(o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return 0;
```

This is wrong..., you're breaking both symmetry and transitivity here.

No need to compare all the world:

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> ...
```

You probably should implement `equals` and `hashCode`. As there are only 52 cards, you could make the constructor private and provide a factory method returning one of the 52 pre-created instances. But you don't have to.

## HandRanker

```
public static final int FULL_HAND = 5;
```

Whenever I see such an int, I think about enums. Something like

```
enum Value implements Predicate<Collection<Card>> {
    FULL_HAND(5) {
        public boolean apply(Collection<Card> cards) {
            ...
        }
    },
    FLUSH(5) {
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

I wanted to copy the body of `isFullHand` to my `Value.FULL_HAND#apply`, but couldn't find it. There would be no such problem with the `enum` as it groups the name, the predicate and the numerical value nicely together. In case an enum wouldn't work, you could still create multiple classes doing the same.

## Pokerhand

Again, `HAND_RANK` should be `HandRank`.

```
this.cards = cards;
Collections.sort(this.cards);
```

You should neither assign a collection without doing a defensive copy, nor should you sort a provided collection (Does every caller know you do? What if I call `new PokerHand(HandRank.HIGH_CARD, ImmutableList.of(....)`?). It may be sometimes acceptable for performance reasons.

## Questions

### 1. Any suggestions how to do it better?

> Should I write some between class for easier testing.

```
import static ...;

public void testStraight() {
    List<Card> cards = ImmutableList.of(
        ACE.of(DIAMONDS),
        ACE.of(SPADES),
        ...
}
```

> You can imagine how much lines it would take to properly test everything.

My above idea saves no lines, just makes them much shorter. You surely need quite a few such tests, but could also write some loops and maybe even some pseudo-random tests?

I see that even something like

```
final ImmutableList<Card> cards = ImmutableList.of(
    TEN.of(SPADES),
    TEN.of(DIAMONDS),
    NINE.of(SPADES),
    EIGHT.of(SPADES),
    EIGHT.of(CLUBS));
final Hand hand = new Hand(cards);
```

is a big pain to write and way beyond reasonable. You'd need a constructor like

```
final Hand hand = new Hand("TS TD 9S 8S 8C");
```

### 2. How could I make HandRanker class structure better?

> To me it seems I'm exploiting stuff that I shouldn't do. Is this a good approach?

The condition should loop over `HandRanker.values()`. **You definitely should not do the strange trick with assigning `pokerHand` in the test.** That's so terrible I completely missed it.

Do not return `boolean` if you want to return `pokerHand`. Return `null` if it doesn't apply....

Something like

```
for (HandRank handRank : HandRank.values() {
     if (handRank.apply(allCards)) return handRank;
}
return null;
```

should also work. I know too little about poker, but there's some redundancy in your code: `HAND_RANK.STRAIGHT` and `HandRanker.STRAIGHT`, which is which?

> Is there something I haven't thought of?

Concurrency?

Anyway, this part is ugly and should be rewritten.

> Also relying on sorting when getting higher card at index 0 in a list seems wrong.

It'd fine if it was your own list. If you sort something private, then you can expect it to stay sorted. But you've sorted a list provided from the outside and someone may have shuffled it in the meantime (at least in theory).

I'd write something like

```
Card getHighest(List<Card> cards) {
     assert isSorted(card);
     return cards.get(0);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with `you're breaking both symmetry and transitivity here.`?

Comment: @user255572 Symmetry: `card.compareTo("abc")` returns `0`, the other way round it blows. Transitivity: Let `card1.compareTo(card2)` be negative, now, because of `card2.compareTo("abc")` being `0`, `card1.compareTo("abc")` should be negative as well (I mean `card1 < card2 = "abc"). If it sounds like non-sense, it's because of it being a non-sense.

Comment: I see. I should make from `TWO` to `ACE` static classes inside a Card class and implement each one a `of` method? Or is there some shortcut?

Comment: @user255572 The enums are fine, just add a `public Card of(Rank rank) {return new Card(this, rank);}` to the `Suit` enum (or the other way round).